# ServiceStack Razor Local Time

Tags: servicestack

ServiceStack Razor page display time is UTC, How to display a Local time?

Code in Backstage:

ServiceModel.Types

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Service.Model

```
[Route("/customers/{id}", "GET", Matches = "**/{int}")]
public class GetCustomer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class GetCustomerResponse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

ServiceInterface

```
public class CustomerService : Service
{
    public AppConfig Config { get; set; }

    [DefaultView("Customer")]
    public object Get(GetCustomer request)
    {
        var customer = Db.SingleById<Customer>(request.Id);
        return new GetCustomerResponse().PopulateWith(customer);
    }
}
```

Code in Page:

```
<span>@Model.CreateDate</span>
```

The CreateDate store in DB is UTC Time, How to convert it to LocalTime in Http Custom hooks. then display in page is LocalTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying Times in [ServiceStack.Razor](http://razor.servicestack.net) is the same as normal C#, e.g:

```
<pre>
Local Time:

@DateTime.Now

UTC Time:

@DateTime.UtcNow

Formatted Local Time:

@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
</pre>
```

Which of the time of this post in EST, renders:

```
Local Time:

1/24/2018 11:12:06 PM

UTC Time:

1/25/2018 4:12:06 AM

Formatted Local Time:

2018/01/24 23:12:06
```

To convert a UTC Time to LocalTime you can use `ToLocalTime()`, e.g:

```
@Model.CreateDate.ToLocalTime()
```

Comment: The response dto has a property is DateTime Type, It's value is a UTC Time, Razor page display a Local Time

Comment: @user2634723 It's impossible to help without any code showing what you're doing. Please update your question with the code used to populate the DTO, the value and Kind of the DateTime, the code you used to display the DateTime and the rendered result.

Comment: I had update the question, how to implement? thanks.

Comment: @user2634723 See my updated answer, i.e. use `.ToLocalTime()`